# Files disappeared from Xcode project, but still in folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Morning I opened my xcode project to do some changes, but all files are disappeared. I don't kno why and I haven't any idea how I can return them back. All files are in folder, but can't see them in project navigation. is there any way to put them back to project?
NOTE: Filter in the Filter Bar is OFF.

[image]

Comment: Restart xcode and open project worksapce again.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna not working. the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project or folder icon in the navigator and select the "Add Files To..." option to add existing files back into a project.